# gulp not running in Dockerfile: Local gulp not found in /

Tags: docker, gulp

This is my Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /mcvitty
COPY . /mcvitty

RUN cd /mcvitty &&\
    npm install -g gulp@3.9.1 &&\
    npm link gulp --force &&\
    npm install jshint@2.9.5 &&\
    npm install gulp-jshint@2.0.4 &&\
    npm install gulp-sass@3.1.0 &&\
    npm install gulp-concat@2.6.1 &&\
    npm install gulp-uglify@3.0.0 &&\
    npm install gulp-rename@1.2.2 &&\
    npm install gulp-minify-css@1.2.4 &&\
    npm install gulp-image-resize@0.13.0  
    
 RUN   gulp
 RUN   gulp resize-images
```

Whenever I run my container I get the following error:

> [08:35:34] Local gulp not found in /
> [08:35:34] Try running: npm install gulp
> The command '/bin/sh -c gulp' returned a non-zero code: 1

Adding

> npm install gulp@3.9.1

to have a local gulp, as suggested by someone does not work either.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you locate the `gulp` executable and check if this is in your `$PATH` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Gulp running in a container. The main differences are that I set a working directory:

```
RUN mkdir /mcvitty
WORKDIR /mcvitty
COPY . /mcvitty
```

I don't run `npm link gulp`, either.

If that doesn't work, remove the `RUN gulp` commands and add them to your `docker run` command, e.g.

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint '/bin/sh' myimage -c 'gulp && gulp images'
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by CD back into my dir before running gulp:

RUN cd /mcvitty && gulp